# Magento 2 How to load product collection, Category collection, Load product by id and get category by product id

Tags: magento-2.1, product, category

I do have experience with magento 1 and in magento 1 i do know how to load the product collection, category collection, quote and product load by id.

Magento 2 is really new concept for me and syntax is completely changed in it. Need help how can i load Product collection, category collection, quote and product by id using magento 2 standard methods.

**Magento 1 Product Collection:**

```
 $productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
```

**How to call product collection in magento 2.**

**Magento 1 Category Collection:**

$categoryCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection();

**How to call category collection in magento 2**

**Magento 1 Load product by id :**

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);
```

**How to load in magento 2**

**Magento 1 load category by product id:**

```
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_item['product_id']);
    $cats = $product->getCategoryIds();
```

**How to load in magento 2?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**CALL PRODUCT COLLECTION**

You need to define dependency as below

```
public function __construct(    
    ....
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,
    ...
)
{    
    $this->_productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;
}

 public function getProductCollection()
{
    $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
    $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
    return $collection;
}
```

For Category collection

```
   protected $_categoryCollection;

   public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory $categoryCollection       
    ) {
        $this->_categoryCollection = $categoryCollection;
    }      

    public function getCategoryCollection()
    {
        $collection = $this->_categoryCollection->create()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*');

        return $collection;
    }
```

**Product Get By ID**

```
  protected $productRepository; 
  protected $_storeManager; 

  public function __construct(
    ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository
  ) {
      $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
  }
  public function getProduct()
  {

      $productId=1;
      return $product = $this->productRepository->getById($productId);
  }
```

You can also do same for load category by product id.

**Category By product ID**

```
protected $_categoryFactory
protected $_productFactory

public function __construct(    
    ....
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $productFactory,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\CategoryFactory $categoryFactory 
    ...
){
    $this->_categoryFactory = $categoryFactory;
    $this->_productFactory = $productFactory;

}

public function getCategoryFromProductId(){
    $product = $this->_productFactory->create()->load($pid);
    $cats = $product->getCategoryIds(); //array
    if(count($cats) ){
        $firstCategoryId = $cats[0];
        $_category = $this->_categoryFactory->create()->load($firstCategoryId);
        return $_category->getName();
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh! does it mean i need to create this code? if i want to call the collection directly in my frontend file or block like magento 1?  is it possible to call it?  Is it standard method to do this?

Comment: yes all are above standard. if you want to call it in template file use above code in block. add dependency and create function as show in answer and use that function in respected template file using `$block->getProductCollection()`

Comment: In Product collection i will get entire product info ?  How do i know about factory methods?

Comment: Yes you will get whole product collection. for factory method refer http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/factories.html

Comment: Thanks for your help.  how can i load category by product id?

Comment: Update answer please check it

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I really appreciate your help.  i stuck in one more problem if you can answer of it:  https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/188940/magento-2-if-we-add-header-and-footer-in-checkout-page-then-payment-method-stop

Comment: I am using `\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory` class to get product collection but I am not able to load product by product Id here, please help

Comment: @PurushotamSharmause Product Get By ID from answer

Comment: I've override a method  "getDefaultSuccessPageUrl"  of the model "\Magento\Checkout\Model\DefaultConfigProvider"  & i've product-id here how can i get category id? i used above solution & it doesn't work.also try the same in controller but it doesn't work.

Comment: Getting error:-  Uncaught TypeError: Argument 8 passed to Test\Clientform\Controller\Index\Index::__construct() must be an instance of Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\CategoryFactory, array given, called

Comment: Earlier, i was using your code in model or controller, but when i used it in block it works for me.thankyou very much.i've a question how can we do the same via controller or model or template?is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

### Magento 2 Product Collection:

In magento2, for *getting product collection at any class*,You should inject Factory class  `Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory`
in __construction function.

```
namespace [YourClassNameSpace];
class [YourClassName]
{
protected $_productCollectionFactory;
 public function __construct(
    ....
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,
    .....
    ) {
    .....
        $this->_productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;
    .....
 }

public function getProductCollection(){

    $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
    /* Addtional */
    $collection
        ->addMinimalPrice() // add for Minimal
        ->addFinalPrice()  // add for Final Price 
        ->addTaxPercents() // add for Tax
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*') // use * for all product  attribute
        ->addUrlRewrite(); // Add for Url   
    return $collection;
}

}
```

### Category collection:

*For **getting categry collection at any class**,You should inject Factory class  `Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory`
in __construction function*

```
namespace [YourClassNameSpace];
class [YourClassName]
{
    protected $_CategoryCollectionFactory;
     public function __construct(
        ....
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory $CategoryCollectionFactory,
        .....
        ) {
        .....
        $this->_CategoryCollectionFactory = $CategoryCollectionFactory;
        .....
     }

    public function getCategoryCollection(){

        $collection = $this->_CategoryCollectionFactory->create();
        /* Addtional */
        $collection
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*') // use * for all Category  attribute
            ->joinUrlRewrite(); // Joins url rewrite rules to collection
        return $collection;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply,   What's use of this code?  $this->_productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;
and in product collection  why we need to do :   $collection
        ->addMinimalPrice() // add for Minimal
        ->addFinalPrice()  // add for Final Price 
        ->addTaxPercents() // add for Tax
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*') // use * for all product  attribute
        ->addUrlRewrite();

Comment: **jack  you need to understand the dependency injection.**   You that `\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory` --> `$this->_productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;`

Comment: ok amitji.  How can i load category from product id and load product by id?