# Magento 2 if we add header and footer in checkout page then payment method stop loading

Tags: magento-2.1, checkout, payment-methods

I want to add header and footer on checkout page. To add that in my theme folder i copied  checkout_index_index.xml file i changed layout to **1column**:

```
 <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
```

and added following code under body

```
    <referenceContainer name="footer-container" remove="false"/>
    <referenceBlock name="minicart" remove="false" />
    <referenceBlock name="top.search" remove="false" />
    <referenceContainer name="header.panel" remove="false" />
    <referenceBlock name="catalog.topnav" remove="false"/>
```

Now header and footers are showing but issue is payment method stopped loading on checkout page.  what could be the issue?

What am i doing wrong here?  Is there any other way to add header and footer on checkout page?

Comment: Check console is there any error?

Comment: No. it's not showing any error.

Answer (score 2):

Try to change the `vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/page_layout/checkout.xml`
  file to 1column instead of the checkout_index_index.xml like

```
<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_layout.xsd">
    <update handle="1column"/>
    <referenceContainer name="page.wrapper">
        <container name="checkout.header.container" as="checkout_header_container" label="Checkout Page Header Container" htmlTag="header" htmlClass="page-header" before="main.content">
            <container name="checkout.header.wrapper" label="Checkout Page Header" as="checkout_header_wrapper" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="header content"/>
        </container>
    </referenceContainer>
</layout>
```

and then in the checkout_index_index.xml add your above code to add the header and footer.